# Is there an easy way to capture the full path of an element in chrome which includes beyond the iframe?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

Let's say we're working with an element in chrome. And it's not clear whether it's inside an iframe or not. You right-click the element > copy > full xpath.

This shows the full xpath but only from the point where the iframe starts. Is there any way to copy the full xpath that includes the parent frame as well?

I'm basically trying to see if there's an easy way to find out whether an element is present inside an iframe instead of visually scrolling through the entire HTML code searching for an "iframe".

I've searched for browser extensions but didn't find anything that can "highlight" the iframes. I've tried highlighting them manually as well by searching for each frame and hovering the mouse on the objects inside it. It's not a good method for finding out whether or not an object is inside an iframe.

Is there a way to get the full path of an HTML element (including the path from the root HTML tag)?

Comment: In any case you should switch to the needed iFrame first; after that you can search its elements.

Comment: Yep. The automation code has to switch to the iframe. I'm talking about the step even before we write the automation code. We need to identify whether an element is inside an iframe. One way is to manually scroll through the code trying to find that one elusive tag "iframe"

Comment: I see one solution: `foreach (frame in frames) { driver.switchTo(frame); if driver.findElements("locator").Count > 0 break; }`

Comment: ^ that is written in pseudo-code.

Comment: Chropath Iframe feature supports this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxzrPW9yLRE&feature=youtu.be and https://autonomiq.io/chropath/

Comment: @SergiiDmytrenko Yes I get it. But we're not talking about the code level. We are talking about the manual inspection that we do before writing the xpath.

Comment: Ok, in this case: open Dev Tools in Chrome (F12); select Console tab; write $x("<your xPath>"); press Enter key. If any control is found - you will see the list, if none -> there is a drop-down with available iFrames just under the 'Console' tab. Select another frame and re-search the elements with $x https://ibb.co/8BvrBz2

Comment: @AmrutaPande This is a beautiful plugin! Feel free to add it as an answer!